# Can anyone help on how to implement a video calling functionality in a react native app?

Tags: react-native

Any help in implementing this video call feature would be helpful! As i am new to react native i have the idea of linking and have implementing phonecall functionality already but can't really figure out for video call

Answer (score 0):

You should check this https://github.com/oney/react-native-webrtc  and  there is a great open source project https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet you can also check this and use as base project.

Comment: Can you please post a snippet for me as i am a newbie in react native

Comment: its not simple code snippet. you can see  in webrtc readme https://github.com/oney/react-native-webrtc#usage

Comment: not helping me and even the tutorials on youtube are of no help !!